# Publishing Rasterdata from PostgreSQL-DB using Mapserver

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I am having a huge table with multiple partitions (one for each day) of processed satellite data stored in a PostgreSQL-DB and want to publish the data using mapserver to serve it as wms.

I am running my database, python and the mapserver in docker containers. Mapserver is camptocamp/mapserver:7.6-20-04, database is based on postgis/postgis:12-3.0 and python is using continuumio/miniconda3:4.12.0 as images.

My processing consists of splitting the data in 1km X 1km tiles and save each of those tiles in the database. I checked and when I load the tiles into QGIS it works perfectly fine and they are exactly where they should be.

If I access the database using mapserver however, there seems to be problems with the georeferencing of the data as the data.

[image: MapserverOutput]

This is how I produce the tiles and create the queries to insert into postgres:

```
def pg_raster_from_file(filepath: str) -> str:
    """Convert rasterfile into a valid postgresql representation"""
    sql_full = subprocess.run(["raster2pgsql", filepath, "public.dummy"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("utf-8")
    sql_raster_plus_suffix = sql_full.split("VALUES (\'")[-1]
    matched = re.match("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+", sql_raster_plus_suffix)
    if matched is not None:
        return matched.group()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"{filepath} does not contain a valid postgis raster")

#%%
def createInsert_1km(x_sw, y_sw, raster10, Date, suffix, sensor):
    insert_data = (int(x_sw),int(y_sw), pg_raster_from_file(raster10),
               Date, suffix == 'coreg',"L2A", sensor,)
    return insert_data



res = 10
data = gdal.Open(f"{res}m_bands.tif")
geoTransform = data.GetGeoTransform()

minx = geoTransform[0]
maxy = geoTransform[3]
maxx = minx + int(res) * data.RasterXSize
miny = maxy - int(res) * data.RasterYSize
floored_minx = math.floor(minx / 1000) * 1000
floored_miny = math.floor(miny / 1000) * 1000
ceiled_maxx = math.ceil(maxx / 1000) * 1000
ceiled_maxy = math.ceil(maxy / 1000) * 1000
bounds = (floored_minx,ceiled_maxy, ceiled_maxx, floored_miny)


x_steps =  np.arange(bounds[0], bounds[2], 1000)
y_steps = np.arange(bounds[3], bounds[1], 1000)

os.mkdir(f"{res}m_tiles")
for x_sw, y_sw in list(itertools.product(x_steps, y_steps)):
    bounds_steps = (x_sw, y_sw + 1000, x_sw+1000, y_sw)
    warpOptions = gdal.WarpOptions(format ="Gtiff", dstSRS = "EPSG:25832",outputBounds = bounds_steps, outputBoundsSRS="EPSG:25832", xRes=res, yRes=res, creationOptions = ["TILED=YES","COMPRESS=LZW"])
    ds = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS =f"{res}m_tiles/{x_sw}_{y_sw}.tif" , srcDSOrSrcDSTab=f"/opt/ts_worker/{res}m_bands.tif",options= warpOptions )
    ds.FlushCache()
    del ds, warpOptions
        
os.remove(f"{res}m_bands.tif")



tiles = glob.glob("10m_tiles/*.tif")
tiles = [t.split("/")[-1] for t in tiles]
tiles = list(set(tiles))

for named_tile in tiles:
        try:
            if( has_values_in_geotiff(f"10m_tiles/{x_sw}_{y_sw}.tif")
                query_val =  createInsert_1km(x_sw, y_sw, f"10m_tiles/{named_tile}",date_pg, "coreg","S2A")
                query_vals.append(query_val)
        except Exception as e:
            if 'find' in str(e):
                not_found += 1
                continue
            if 'found' in str(e):
                not_found += 1
                continue
            else:
                print(e)
                continue
```

And this is the corresponding layer of my mapfile (I tried removing the filter etcc, didnt help)

```
   LAYER
    NAME sentinel_2rgb
    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    VALIDATION
        "table" "s2_20[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]"
    END
    DATA "PG:host=host port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=pw table=%table% column=b02_b03_b04_b08_msk mode=2"
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    PROCESSING "BANDS=3,2,1"
    FILTER "x_sw between '%xmin'::integer and '%xmax'::integer and y_sw between '%ymin'::integer and '%ymax'::integer"
    METADATA
        wms_title "sentinel_2rgb"
        wms_abstract "abstract"
        wms_srs "EPSG:25832"
        wms_extend "-1877994.66 3932281.56 836715.13 9440581.95"
    END
END
```